# How to add raw dkim record

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, dkim

I need to add my DKIM record as a text entry to my DNS.

I have succeeded doing this for one domain already - cPanel gave me an entry like this:

```
default._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=[lots of numbers and letters];"
```

which I successfully added to my DNS like this:

```
Host: default._domainkey
TXT: v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=[lots of numbers and letters];
```

with removed "".

Now I'm trying to add another domain. The entry is a little different. This time it's:

```
default._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=[lots of numbers and letters]" [lots of numbers and letters]\;
```

Please pay attention to the fact that there's 2 strings of letters and numbers, and only one of them is enclosed in `""`.

I can't get this to register correct. I add the host as `default._domainkey` and have tried added the rest as text both with and without the "".

What would be the correct format for this?

Comment: What does the _actual_ entry look like? I mean, without all the [substitutions]. You're putting it in DNS, there's no need for silly paranoia.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following:

```
Host: default._domainkey
TXT: v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=[lots of numbers and letters]" [lots of numbers and letters];
```

You just need to replaced `/;` with `;` at the end and it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the double quotes from two strings and join them together. Make sure there is no whitespaces in the strings. Finally, replace the `/;` with `;` at the end. Please see below:

```
Host: default._domainkey
TXT: v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=[lots of numbers and letters][lots of numbers and letters];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you of 2x `[lots of numbers and letters]` is because the `TXT` record in sum is longer than 255 characters so the key needs to be broken into chunks.

This happens when you use a larger key size than `1024`.

If your DKIM key in the Data field exceeds 255 characters and you do not break it up with quotes, you will receive an error.